# how to add .txt file to a JTextArea and where to place my .txt file?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

i'm working on my first GUI program and almost finished the last class is a jFrame that has a .txt file and a button to close the window and i don't know how to append my file into the window ???
package eg.edu.guc.santorini.gui;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Rules extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener{
JPanel Rules;
JTextArea  rules;
public Rules() throws IOException
{
    super();
    setTitle("Rules Of Santorini Board Game");
    setSize(1000, 700);
    setLocation(200, 100);
    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(new Color(220,20,60));
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    WindowDestroyer wd = new WindowDestroyer();
    addWindowListener(wd);

    JTextArea  rules=new JTextArea();
    rules.append("");


    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // read a text file from resources folder that is parallel to src folder
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new               File("resources/New Text Document.txt")));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // read the file line by line
        builder.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    reader.close();

    // set the content of file in text area
    textArea.setText(builder.toString());

       /* FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("New Text Document.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

String inputFile = "";
String textFieldReadable = bufferedReader.readLine();

while (textFieldReadable != null){
    inputFile += textFieldReadable;
    textFieldReadable = bufferedReader.readLine();                    
    rules.setText(inputFile);*/



    Rules=new JPanel();
    Rules.setLayout(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Rules.setVisible(true);
    Rules.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    add(Rules, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Rules.setSize(1000, 700);
    this.getContentPane().add(Rules);


    JButton ok=new JButton("Got It");
    ok.setSize(100, 50);
    ok.setLocation(800, 570);
    ok.addMouseListener(this);
    Rules.add(ok);

    ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //dispose();
            setVisible(false);

        }
  });

    //JFrame f = new JFrame();
    //f.setSize(320, 200);
    //f.getContentPane().add(rules);
    //f.setVisible(true);



}




@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the content of text file inside the `JTextArea`? or you are not able to read the file?

Comment: i want to show the content in the window

Comment: actually i want it on my window but when searched couldn't find how to show it

Comment: Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen. Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

Answer (score 4):

> where to place my .txt file?

You can try any one

```
// Read from same package 
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt");

// Read from resources folder parallel to src in your project
File file = new File("resources/abc.txt");

// Read from src/resources folder
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/abc.txt");
```

[image]

---

--EDIT--

**Must read [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).**

Here is some points from your code:

- Don't use `null` layout `Rules.setLayout(null);`
- Call `JFrame#setVisible(true);` in the end when all the components are added
- Always use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to initialize the GUI
- Follow Java Naming convention.

Comment: the problem is after throwing exception another class requires try catch block after wards initializing the class Rules = null and a problem that i dont know how to handle appears

Comment: `textArea` is not added in the `JFrame`. second you have created a local as well as instance variable for `rules`

Comment: Don't throw it .use `try-catch` block.

Comment: how to add textArea to Jframe this is my first project on GUI and its self study so i dont know how

Comment: there is lot of issues in your code. don't use `null` layout.

Comment: if u can edit the code and again answer the question and know that i placed my file in the resources folder

Comment: That's working fine. file is picking perfectly from resources folder. OK let me code for you.

Comment: This entire saga suggests you are in over your head.  A programmer should be comfortable with basics like exception handling before attempting an app. with a GUI.  +1 to Braj for their effort here.

Comment: @user2419300 I have added the code for you but you have to learn a lot. Don't be hurry just keep learning.

Comment: You're making assumptions about project structure, file locations and work environments...I've not seen any mention of embedded resources (or missing files) or development environments mentioned by the OP, beware ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer OP is in learning state. OP don't know how to read a file? where is put it in the project? etc...

Answer (score 4):

To read a file into a `JTextArea` you can simply use [`JTextArea#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29), this will, however, discard the current contents of the `JTextArea`

**Updated**

After adding the code to an IDE, I've noted that you are not adding `rules` (the `JTextArea`) to anything so it will never be visible...

The general structure of how you create your UI is also a little skewed, try something more like...

```
public class Rules extends JFrame {

    public Rules() throws IOException {
        super();
        // Initial setu[
        setTitle("Rules Of Santorini Board Game");

        // Create the basic UI content
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(40, 20);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        // Read the file
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/New Text Document.txt")))) {
            textArea.read(reader, "File");
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        JButton ok = new JButton("Got It");
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(ok, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //dispose();
                //?? No idea what this is for, but it won't do much
                setVisible(false);

            }
        });

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Don't use `MouseListener`s with buttons, instead you should be using an `ActionListener`

Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen.

Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

Comment: Its' a perfect solution.

Comment: @Braj Don't know if it's perfect, but it's simple ;)